# insertion and updation in while loop php

Tags: php

```
$sql="SELECT activity,work_order FROM works";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    if($row['work_order']==$work_order && $row['activity']==$activity){
        $sql="UPDATE works SET wei_out='$wei_out',len_out='$len_out',end_time='$end_time' WHERE work_order='$work_order' AND activity='$activity'";
        break;
    }
    else{
        $sql="INSERT INTO works (jobno,date,start_time,work_order,worker,activity,status,len_in,wei_in,grams) values ('$jobno','$date','$start_time','$work_order','$worker','$activity','$status','$len_in','$wei_in','$grams')";
        break;
    }
}
```

the above code for insertion and updation in while loop is not working can anyone help me by solving

Comment: Please use MySQLi or PDO, `mysql_*` functions are deprecated in PHP 5 and removed in PHP 7.

Comment: https://phpdelusions.net/pdo

Comment: **Don't** use the **deprecated and insecure** _mysql_*-functions. They have been deprecated since PHP 5.5 (in 2013) and were completely removed in PHP 7 (in 2015). Use MySQLi or PDO instead. 2. You are **wide open to** [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of concatenating your queries, which can be used if you use the above mentioned MySQLi or PDO.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot your `mysqli_query();` in your for loop.  And please use `mysqli_*` not `mysql_*`.

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "my_db");

$sql = "SELECT activity, work_order FROM works";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

// Don't forget to escape your input!
$len_out    = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $len_out);
$wei_out    = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $wei_out);
$end_time   = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $end_time);
$start_time = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $start_time);
$work_order = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $work_order);
$activity   = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $activity);
$jobno      = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $jobno);
$date       = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $date);
$worker     = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $worker);
$status     = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $status);
$len_in     = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $len_in);
$wei_in     = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $wei_in);
$grams      = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $grams);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    if ($row['work_order'] == $work_order && $row['activity'] == $activity) {
        $sql = "UPDATE works SET wei_out='$wei_out', len_out='$len_out', end_time='$end_time' WHERE work_order='$work_order' AND activity='$activity'";
        mysqli_query($con, $sql);  // Run the query
        break;
    } else {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO works (jobno, date, start_time, work_order, worker, activity, status, len_in, wei_in, grams) VALUES ('$jobno', '$date', '$start_time', '$work_order', '$worker', '$activity', '$status', '$len_in', '$wei_in', '$grams')";
        mysqli_query($con, $sql);  // Run the query
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: @RevanthOleti:  you need to specify exactly what "not working" means. What are you expecting that does not appear to be working?

Comment: The code is not updating it is only inserting the data.But i want to insert and update in the same while loop with tha above conditions.

Comment: Are you sure that your `$work_order` and `$activity` variables have the value you are expecting ?  You could try `echo $activity;echo $work_order;` to make sure.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to execute the statement stored in `$sql` variable and its good to use `mysqli` for your security issue.

```
$sql="SELECT activity,work_order FROM works";
$result=mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    if($row['work_order']==$work_order && $row['activity']==$activity){
        $sql="UPDATE works SET wei_out='".$wei_out."',len_out='".$len_out."',end_time='".$end_time."' WHERE work_order='".$work_order."' AND activity='".$activity."'";
        mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
        break;
    }
    else{
        $sql="INSERT INTO works (jobno,date,start_time,work_order,worker,activity,status,len_in,wei_in,grams) values ('".$jobno."','".$date."','".$start_time."','".$work_order."','".$worker."','".$activity."','".$status."','".$len_in."','".$wei_in."','".$grams."')";
        mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
        break;
    }
}
```